# Python grading system using if and for

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of name = `jimmy, carolin, frank, joseph`
and their score is = `100 , 90, 70, 65`

The grades are :

```
A = 95 - 100
B = 80 - 94
C = 70 - 79
D = 60 - 69
E = 0 - 59
```

and I put it like this

```
students = ["jimmy", "carolin", "frank", "joseph"]

scores = ["100", "90", "70", "65"]

if scores >= 95 and scores <=100: 
    return "A"
elif scores >= 80 and scores <=94: 
    return "B"
elif scores >= 70 and scores <=79: 
    return "C"
elif scores >= 60 and scores <=69: 
    return "D"
else: 
    return "E"
```

I need to make it like this:

```
jimmy, 100, A
carolin, 90, B
frank, 70, C
joseph, 65, D
```

Can some one help me please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can use dictionary with name as key and marks as values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
students = ["jimmy", "carolin", "frank", "joseph"]

scores = ["100", "90", "70", "65"]

def function(scores):
    if scores >= 95 and scores <=100:
        return "A"
    elif scores >= 80 and scores <=94:
        return "B"
    elif scores >= 70 and scores <=79:
        return "C"
    elif scores >= 60 and scores <=69:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "E"

for student in students:
    print (student + "," + str(scores[students.index(student)]) + "," + function(int(scores[students.index(student)])))
```

I added everything in one print statement, hope you can understand. Your if else function is also added into a function for easier use.

For the score, I'm assuming the student's index would be similar with the score's index

You should receive the following output:

```
jimmy,100,A
carolin,90,B
frank,70,C
joseph,65,D
```

Comment: Python lets you chain conditions so you are allowed to have `if 95 <= score <= 100:`, though you have redundant checks. your first elif should be `elif score >= 80:` because you already know its `< 95` after failing the first condition.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function to return the grade based on your scoring matrix. You can then `zip` all the results into a list of `tuples` in the need of accessing them later.

```
def get_grade(score):
    scores = [('A', 95, 100), ('B', 80, 94), ('C', 70, 79), ('D', 60, 69), ('E', 0, 59)]
    result = [grade for grade, low, high in scores if score >= low and score <= high]
    return result[0] if result else 'Invalid Score'


students = ["jimmy", "carolin", "frank", "joseph"]
scores = ["100", "90", "70", "65"]
grades = [get_grade(int(i)) for i in scores]

results = list(zip(students, scores, grades))

for name, score, result in results:
    print(name, score, result)
```

Output:

```
jimmy 100 A
carolin 90 B
frank 70 C
joseph 65 D
```

Answer (score 0):

## Create a dictionary of Grades to Score Range Mappings

```
gradeMap = {
"A" : (95, 100),
"B" : (80, 94),
"C" : (70, 90),
"D" : (60, 69),
"E" : (0, 59)
}
```

## Convert Score to Grade

Write a function that takes a score and a **grade-map** and returns the corresponding grade.

```
def score_to_grade(score, gm):
    for (g, (min_score, max_score)) in gm.items():
        if (score >= min_score and score < max_score):
            return g
```

## Interesting thing to notice

One interesting thing that this situation allows us to notice is as follows:

The dictionary `gradeMap` is very much like a function with grade letters (A, B, etc) as the domain and a pair of non-negative numbers as the range.

You can rewrite any function as a dictionary if the domain is a set of a finite and small number of values.